# Comparar un texto con un array multidimensional con expresiones regulares

Tags: php, array, regex

Sinceramente he probado con `in_array`, `array_search` y no he podido hacerlo. Tengo, por ejemplo el siguiente Array:

```
$arg = array( 
    "vimeo"=>array(
        "link" => '/https?:\/\/[w\.]*vimeo\.[^\/]*\/([^?]*)/is'
    ),

    "dailymotion"=>array(
        "link" => '/https?:\/\/[w\.]*dailymotion\.[^\/]*\/([^?]*)/is',
    ),
);
```

Me gustaria recorrer el array y encontrar una coicidencia, pero en todos los casos me dice que no hay coicidencias. Como deberia hacerlo

```
if(in_array($input, $arg)){
    echo "Hay coincidencias";
}else{
    echo "No hay coincidencias";
    echo " -> ";
    echo $input;
```

El input toma una URL de un formulario y quiero saber si el link corresponde a alguna de las dos webs

Comment: Nicolás, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Por favor, di qué es lo que quieres comparar, da datos reales, porque con los valores `$input, $this->site` no podemos probar los datos, ni saber qué es lo que quieres exactamente.

Comment: El input toma una URL de un formulario y quiero saber si el link corresponde a alguna de las dos webs

Comment: Pero, ¿cómo son las URLs que toma el input, y cuál es el valor de `$this->site`? Al preguntar debes ofrecer unos datos reales para poder reproducir el problema y darte una respuesta concreta, basada en código.

Comment: $arg = array( 
            "vimeo"=>array(
                  "link" => '/https?:\/\/[w\.]*vimeo\.[^\/]*\/([^?]*)/is'
                          ),

            "dailymotion"=>array(
                  "link" => '/https?:\/\/[w\.]*dailymotion\.[^\/]*\/([^?]*)/is',
                                ),
            );

Comment: if(in_array($input, $arg)){

                echo "Hay coincidencias";

                }else{

                echo "No hay coincidencias";
                echo " -> ";
                echo $input;

Comment: El problema es que `in_array` no espera un array multidimensional como segundo parámetro, por eso te regresa `false` siempre

Comment: Porque estaria mal?

Comment: Ahora si no entiendo

Comment: @C00LMasterN ¿podrías [edit] tu pregunta agregando el valor de `$input` y el resultado esperado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si he entendido bien, tú tienes:

- dos expresiones regulares dentro de un array asociativo
- y una URL cualquiera tomada de un input

Y por lo que se ve, tú quieres verificar si la URL del input cumple con las expresiones regulares que hay dentro de tu array.

Entonces, una forma de hacerlo sería así:

**NOTA:** He modificado el código original, evaluando solamente el elemento `link` del array, para que el código sea más específico y la lógica no falle si en un futuro decides agregar más pares clave/valor a ese array.

```
<?php

$arg = array( 
                "vimeo"=>      array("link" => '/https?:\/\/[w\.]*vimeo\.[^\/]*\/([^?]*)/is' ),
                "dailymotion"=>array("link" => '/https?:\/\/[w\.]*dailymotion\.[^\/]*\/([^?]*)/is',),
            );

$input="https://www.dailymotion.com/is/video";
compararURL($input,$arg);

$input="https://www.dailymotionsss.com/is/video";
compararURL($input,$arg);

$input="https://www.vimeo.com/is/894regqvideo";
compararURL($input,$arg);

$input="https://www.example.com";
compararURL($input,$arg);



function compararURL($input,$arg){
    foreach ($arg as $k=>$v){
        if (preg_match($v["link"], $input)){
            echo "Hay coincidencias con: ".$v["link"]." ";
            echo $input.PHP_EOL;
        }else{
            echo "No hay coincidencias con ".$v["link"];
            echo " -> ";
            echo $input.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

#### Resultados de prueba

```
No hay coincidencias con /https?:\/\/[w\.]*vimeo\.[^\/]*\/([^?]*)/is -> https://www.dailymotion.com/is/video
Hay coincidencias con: /https?:\/\/[w\.]*dailymotion\.[^\/]*\/([^?]*)/is https://www.dailymotion.com/is/video
No hay coincidencias con /https?:\/\/[w\.]*vimeo\.[^\/]*\/([^?]*)/is -> https://www.dailymotionsss.com/is/video
No hay coincidencias con /https?:\/\/[w\.]*dailymotion\.[^\/]*\/([^?]*)/is -> https://www.dailymotionsss.com/is/video
Hay coincidencias con: /https?:\/\/[w\.]*vimeo\.[^\/]*\/([^?]*)/is https://www.vimeo.com/is/894regqvideo
No hay coincidencias con /https?:\/\/[w\.]*dailymotion\.[^\/]*\/([^?]*)/is -> https://www.vimeo.com/is/894regqvideo
No hay coincidencias con /https?:\/\/[w\.]*vimeo\.[^\/]*\/([^?]*)/is -> https://www.example.com
No hay coincidencias con /https?:\/\/[w\.]*dailymotion\.[^\/]*\/([^?]*)/is -> https://www.example.com
```

Comment: Realmente creo que podíamos esperar una aclaración del autor antes de responder.

Comment: Lo único que veo en ambos regex es que el flag `/s` es innecesario, y que el grupo `([^?]*)` del final es totalmente innecesario.

Comment: Cierto @Mariano. Por el código se intuía que esa era la intención, así que me lancé a responder. En cuanto a la nota, no sé lo que pasó, pero había otra expresión regular que me daba : `“Unknown modifier” error`...

Comment: Je, je... no, ya lo encontré. [Al principio estaba así](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/131258/1): `/https?://[w.]vimeo.[^/]/([^?]*)/is`, sabía que no estaban iguales.

Comment: @A.Cedano, el resultado en tu respuesta se puede ver afectado si el OP agrega, además de `link`, algún otro valor para cada sitio. Con esto solo quiero decir que me parece innecesario hacer el segundo `foreach`

Comment: Cierto @Marcos, es mejor indicar explícitamente que se quiere verificar el valor de la clave `link`. Editaré la respuesta. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Una solución podría ser la siguiente:

- Usar [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php) para iterar el arreglo `$arg`
- Usar [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php) para comprobar si el valor de `$input` cumple la expresión regular.

#### Ejemplo:

```
$arg = array(
    "vimeo" => array(
        "link" => '/https?:\/\/[w\.]*vimeo\.[^\/]*\/([^?]*)/is'
     ),
    "dailymotion" => array(
        "link" => '/https?:\/\/[w\.]*dailymotion\.[^\/]*\/([^?]*)/is',
    ),
);
$input = 'https://vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/250383662';
$match = false;

// Por cada valor en $arg
foreach($arg as $site => $data) {

    // Si el valor de $input cumple la RE de sitio
    if (preg_match($data['link'], $input)) {
        $match = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($match) {
    echo "Hay coincidencias";
} else {
    echo "No hay coincidencias";
    echo " -> ";
    echo $input;
}
```

Comment: Realmente creo que podíamos esperar una aclaración del autor antes de responder.

Comment: @Mariano, el OP comento: ["_El input toma una URL de un formulario y quiero saber si el link corresponde a alguna de las dos webs_"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/131258/problema-con-array-multidimensional-php/131272#comment244712_131258). Si aún asi consideras que no esta claro, procedo a eliminar mi respuesta.

Comment: lo más probable es que esté correcto (yo hubiese contestado exactamente lo mismo con la información que presentó). No obstante, convengamos que los datos no tienen el formato más simple, y probablemente quiera obtener el `$site`. Además, está usando el grupo `([^?]*)` al final del regex, por lo que perfectamente podríamos esperar que quiera capturar esa parte... Todo eso son cosas que creo que tenemos que esperar a que se aclaren, antes de responder y encontrarnos con comentarios del autor pidiendo algo más.